# Git Server Binding Directory To Port

Tags: ssh, apache-httpd, git, proxy

I have a git server i have stood up. It is a basic one with all the remote repositories stored under

```
      /mygit/repo/
```

I can push and pull and all the other git stuff using this ssh syntax

```
   ssh://git@myserver/mygit/repo/proj.git
```

However due to circumstances i need to be able to do the same using this ssh syntax

```
   ssh://git@myserver:2200/proj.git
```

Now this where i am getting stuck, i have tried using apache to act as a redirect proxy to expand / into /mygit/repo using this in my .conf under conf.d

```
     Listen 2200
    <VirtualHost *:2200>
       RedirectMatch "^/$" "/mygit/repo/"
       DocumentRoot "/mygit/repo/"
    </VirtualHost>
```

I tried using AllowCONNECT 22 to try and port forward port 2200 to 22 on the git server while doing an expand of the path to file.

Comment: If you're using the `ssh` protocol and want `ssh` on port 2200 to work, then why are you changing the `http` configuration?  Am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hey stephen, i wanted to use apache as a reverse proxy to do absolute path expandsion and port forwarding to port 22 from 2200. However i tried other things and have altered the sshd_conf to allow connection to the server via ssh on port 2200. The command for git works with the ssh and the new port. I am now stuck trying to work out how to limit the absolute path and shorten it. As of right now the git command starts in / and looks for proj.git there.

Comment: Also what i am trying to achieve is to have my ssh commands change from git clone ssh://git@myserver/mygit/repo/proj.git to git clone  ssh://git@myserver:2200/proj.git

Comment: Apache can only reverse proxy the http protocol, not the ssh protocol.  If you want to do port forwarding then look at `iptables` or something like a user space process such as `plugdaemon` ( http://www.taronga.com/plugdaemon/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty i managed to work out the answer. Everything needs to be done as root for the chroot jailed git repo to work.
So the first thing to do is to setup a chroot jail directory

```
  /git/server/repos
```

This handy guide shows how the process is done https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/
Once you have a chrooted jail for the git user you configure the sshd_config and add

```
Port 2200
```

Restart the sshd service. Then you need to add a usr directory followed by bin to the chroot jail and move the git commands.

```
 mkdir -p usr/bin

 cp -v /usr/bin/git* /usr/bin/
```

There are library files needed for the git commands so running ldd on the command in the bin directory will give you the name of the lib file.

```
ldd /usr/bin/git
```

The lib file i had and copied was

```
cp -v /lib64/libz.so.1/lib64/
```

Now you create your git repo as per normal but it must be as root as everything else and then you

```
chmod -R 777 mygitrepo.git
```

Now you chrooted git user can push and pull from the repo using the git commands under syntax

```
ssh://git@myserver:2200/mygitrepo.git
```

Rather than the absolute path if git wasn't chroot jailed

```
ssh://git@myserver:2200/git/server/repos/mygitrepo.git
```